# fSpy doesn't work with vertical pictures

Tags: camera, import, fspy

I've been trying to camera match a vertical picture with fSpy into blender. When importing a picture into fSpy, the program automatically turns it into landscape mode and it seems that there is no way for me to change that.

Of course it is possible to manually rotate the camera and the background picture after importing fSpy file into Blender, but I find this very tedious and manual.

If anyone knows how to make this process automatic, please let me know! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean portrait picture? Can you give screenshots for better understanding

Comment: Yes, I mean portrait. Portrait is the same as vertical and landscape is the same as horizontal. Btw why do you need screenshots? The question is clear and simple. One who needs more explaining probably hasn't ever used fSpy themselves.

Comment: I've never had that problem with fspy. But it sounds like a bug. Try contacting the creator directly on the github page https://github.com/stuffmatic/fSpy/issues

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question on a bug or a feature missing in an external app. Not really a question about blender.

Comment: To help anyone who finds this, I took an image in portrait mode on my Pixel 2, and I had the same problem where fspy would only load the image rotated 90 degrees. I was able to get the image to load properly by opening the photo with the default windows photo app, though any photo editor would likely work, and just saving a copy of the photo. This copy then opened properly. There must be some metadata which is being formatted differently or not read properly by fspy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

This is the portrait (vertical) picture from the picture above, it didn't turn to landscape.

I do use Fspy very well, and it is far better than Blam. And since I've been using Fspy, I've not encounter any error

Comment: Okay... It seems that every vertical picture taken with my Samsung S5 gets turned sideways but pictures taken with the same device in landscape mode stay untouched. I also tried downloading some vertical pictures from google and interestingly enough THESE stayed in this way... This is very interesting topic and I try to reach developers about it.

Comment: That sounds funny